# How can i get rid of the space between the upload button and the country textinput?

Tags: android, image

How to remove the space above after setting the height?
[image: The space between the upload button and country text input]

This is how i set the image height.Am trying to display the image in a card including the a few items, but if the height is set to wrap-content, the image over laps the texts below. Basically i want to get rid of that space and also set the height to 160dp

```
    imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);
    imageview.getLayoutParams().height = 160;
```

My xml is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_first_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/first_name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/first_Name"
            style="@style/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/last_name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/last_Name"
        style="@style/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/farmer_organisation"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/farmer_organisation"
        style="@style/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/acreage"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/acreage"
        style="@style/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/gender"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/genderSpinner"
        style="@style/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/gender" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/crop"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cropSpinner"
        style="@style/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/crops" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/country"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/countrySpinner"
        style="@style/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/countries" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_district"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/district"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/districtSpinner"
            style="@style/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/district" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_sub_county"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/sub_county"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sub_county"
            style="@style/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_parish"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/parish"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/parish"
            style="@style/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_village"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/village"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/village"
            style="@style/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_pic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"
        android:text="@string/upload_photo"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/uploadButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your XML is only showing an imageview so it is not possible to see your mistake

Comment: In your screenshot, where is the ImageView? Please post the complete xml.

Comment: I have now added the entire xml

Comment: Using nested LinearLayout is poor for performance. Have you considered alternatives?

Comment: Yes, when i try without  imageview.getLayoutParams().height = 160;  It fine.The space comes due to height i set as 160. I want the heght to remain but also get rid of the space

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linear Layout in vertical orientation , and then design the structure , it will help you out to get rid of the space , well show me the entire code to have a understanding of your structure of the code why it is inserting space.

Comment: I have added the entire xml. The space comes due to height i set as 160. I want the height to remain but also get rid of the space